# Recursive nearest neighbour to find shortest route

Tags: postgis

I am trying to find the shortest route using resursive nearest neighbours. Here is my code:

```
with RECURSIVE NearestNeighbor AS (
    SELECT
        a.uuid AS from_area,
        b.uuid AS to_area,
        ST_Distance(a."centerPoint"::geography , b."centerPoint"::geography) AS distance,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.uuid ORDER BY ST_Distance(a."centerPoint"::geography, b."centerPoint"::geography)) AS nearest_rank
    FROM
        potential_missed_areas AS a
    CROSS JOIN
        potential_missed_areas AS b
    WHERE
        a.uuid <> b.uuid
        and 
        a.status = 'approved'
        and 
        b.status = 'approved'
        and 
        a."areaID"='007af142-75a3-4678-975a-29f78b92af05'
        and 
        b."areaID" ='007af142-75a3-4678-975a-29f78b92af05'
        
),
RoutePermutations AS (
    SELECT
        a.from_area AS start_area,
        a.to_area,
        a.distance,
        ARRAY[a.to_area] AS visited_areas
    FROM
        NearestNeighbor a
    WHERE
        a.nearest_rank = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        b.start_area,
        a.to_area,
        b.distance + a.distance,
        b.visited_areas || a.to_area
    FROM
        NearestNeighbor a
    INNER JOIN
        RoutePermutations b ON a.from_area = b.to_area
    WHERE
        a.nearest_rank = 1
),
CalculatedRoutes AS (
    SELECT
        start_area,
        visited_areas,
        distance,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY start_area ORDER BY distance) AS route_rank
    FROM
        RoutePermutations
),
ShortestRoute AS (
    SELECT
        start_area,
        visited_areas,
        distance
    FROM
        CalculatedRoutes
    WHERE
        route_rank = 1
)
SELECT
    start_area,
    visited_areas,
    distance
FROM
    ShortestRoute;
```

The issues is that this is taking many minutes for just 6 points!

Comment: Looks to me like you are looking for the M*inimum* S*panning* T*ree* between all `potential_missed_areas."centerPoint"`s? If so, [this](https://gist.github.com/geozelot/a9c461383e11c22d1ff675eb02a752d5#file-point_set_minimum_spanning_tree-sql) (or [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/418988/93656) initial answer on GIS.SE) should help you. The *(K)NN* implementation in your query above is highly inefficient.

Comment: @geozelot I dont get  what "WHERE  g.<id> = 1  " does, is it selecting a hardcoded id value? talking about the implementation in the first link.

Comment: Yes, it just picks a first node to begin with - it doesn't matter which one.  Note that this algorithm is strictly designed for point sets only.